# how do i check smtp server is connected or not?

Tags: php, smtp

I am having two smtp. I want to send newsletter through smtp from two systems. If the one system is already established smtp connection then how do i know the established smtp from the other system?
any idea?

Comment: Wouldn't you just look at the php.ini and see what SMTP is set up in it?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your php.ini file following setting and set accordingly

```
   http://php.net/smtp
   SMTP = localhost;
    http://php.net/smtp-port
    smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: I have a requirement to check if SMTP server is up and running using java


I want to open connection to SMTP server and send some message and get the response code. if response code is something 250 then I will return working status to the caller. Please provide me sample code